# How to do pass dynamic url link into inline css in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, url, inline

`<div mat-card-avatar  style= "background-image: url('{{ user.avatar }}');">`

I want to pass in url data into Angular template inline style.
What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing it in the following way:

```html
<div mat-card-avatar  [ngStyle]="{ background: 'url(' + user.avatar + ')'}">
```